# Add class in datepicker using beforeShow()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to add a class on the selected date element using this function:

`beforeShow:function(){ $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").addClass('testX') }`

I have two issues. First, no such class has been added. Second, the log shows a strange behavior. The first two times that I open the datePicker, `hasClass()` returns false but on the third time shows true (while the `testX` class still not shown in the html).

```js
 $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(){     
      console.log('================================================');
      console.log($( ".ui-datepicker-current-day" ).hasClass('testX'));
      $( ".ui-datepicker-current-day" ).addClass('testX');
      console.log($( ".ui-datepicker-current-day" ).hasClass('testX'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
.testX{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a datepicker example using jquery, jquery ui, and jquery css</p>
<form>
Date:
<input id="datepicker">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use this `.ui-datepicker-today{ background-color:red; }`

Comment: I want to highlight the selected-by-the-user date, not the current(today) date (although it's certainly misleading that jQuery names as `current` the selected date and as `today` the current day.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            afterShow: function () {
                console.log('================================================');
                console.log($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass('testX'));
                $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").addClass('testX');
                console.log($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass('testX'));
            }
        });
```

The above code has been updated you can use onfous event on #datetimepicker. 
the below given code might be helpful for you. it works for me.

```
  $(function () {

       $("#datepicker").focus(function(){
              console.log('================================================');
                console.log($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass('testX'));
                $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").addClass('testX');
                console.log($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass('testX'));

         });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```js
var selectedDay = new Date().getDate();
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            selectedDay = inst.selectedDay;
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            if (date.getDate() == selectedDay && !$('#datepicker').val()=="") {
                return [true, "testX", ""]; 
            } else {
                return [true, ""]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
.testX{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a datepicker example using jquery, jquery ui, and jquery css</p>
<form>
Date:
<input id="datepicker">
</form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps